# Peel away website effect with javascript only

Tags: javascript

I have seen corner screen peel away effects that use flash (swf files). Does anyone know of code that does this with Javascript/css alone?

Thanks

Comment: Jquery can make your answer...

Comment: Please link to an example of the effect you want to recreate.

Comment: JQuery did it. http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/jquery-peel-back-ad/ Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the jquery plugin demos here 
[Some examples](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-page-peel-plugins/)

Comment: You should really pull a few examples *into* your answer, otherwise it'll be worthless if the site ever goes down.